# Get Current URL in Magento including sub-pages of that URL and show something

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, magento-1.9

I already know how to get a specific URL in Magento and show something. It was already resolved in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192212/get-current-url-in-magento-and-show-something

However, I noticed that it will only show what I want to show in the page alone. If I browse through its subpages, it doesn't show anymore.

For example the URL of my magento site is magento.com. And want to show something in magento.com/blog, thus I'll use this method:

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$path = $url->getPath();
$blogPaths = array('/blog', '/blog/', '/index.php/blog/');
if(in_array($path, $blogPaths))
{
    //Do something on /blog
}
```

However, when I browse to a specific page on that subpage, for example, magento.com/blog/another-page-within-the-blog-page, the element that I'm trying to show disappears. It only appears in magento.com/blog

How can I let it appear in /blog, and all the pages under /blog?

I have tried array /blog/* but it didn't work. I guess what I did is simply not right. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question in stackoverflow and it was resolved using this solution.

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}

$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$path = $url->getPath();
if (startsWith($path, '/blog/') || (strcmp($path, '/blog') == 0))
{
    //Do something on /blog and all pages underneath
}
```

This are for those who are having the same problem like me. :D

SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297270/show-something-in-a-subpage-and-all-pages-under-that-subpage-in-php/25298390#25298390